# Implement Webhook in Client-Side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webhooks, asyncsocket

I'm using some client-side JavaScript to make some `API` calls that return data to an end user. I'd like to use a `Webhook` (rather than polling the API) to get updated information from the API when it's available, but not sure if this is even since my `JS` is only client-side and has to be **lightweight** (e.g. I rather not rely on loading any libraries).

Would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with loading libraries. Todays webpages heavily rely on libraries and albeit you can overdo it, loading a library is nothing which makes your page "heavy". You are better off doublechecking your image sizes when you optimize for size.

For webhook implementations I would recommend websockets. A nice libarary for this purpose is [socket.io](https://socket.io/). With websockets you can push data from the server to the client so you dont rely on polling.